# How to import relative module python

Tags: python

folder structure

```
 root/
     fisrt/
          x.py
          y.py
```

```
# x.py

from . import y
```

This will get an error , **ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package**

I have seached a lot of `relavtive module import` information.

There are  other question in stackoverflow talk about import, but I still can not figure out.

Comment: Add the error to the explanation

Comment: @Deepan I have no idea what do you mean

Comment: Add `__init__.py` file in `first` folder

Comment: @Deepan it is not work. I still get same ImportError

Comment: `$ export PYTHONPATH=/your/dir/here/"`

Comment: Just use `import y`

Comment: @OrenIshShalom `$ export PYTHONPATH=/your/dir/here/"`, I dont know what is this mean

Comment: Are you working on linux or windows ?

Comment: @Deepan I know I can jsut `import y`, but I want to use relative import instead. Maybe I will use relative import some day

Comment: @OrenIshShalom windows

Comment: use this for setting `PYTHONPATH` on windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901684/3357352

Answer (score 0):

They are both in the same directory, so you don't need to use `from`; just use `import y`.

Say if you were to move `y.py` to a new directory labelled `example`, (see the following file structure example,) you would use `from example import y`.

```
x.py
example/
    y.py
```

Comment: Using `import y` to import a module in your folder only makes sense if there are no packages involved. If either `root` or `first` in the example are supposed to be packages, then such an implicit relative import only works in Python 2 (which nobody should be using at this point).